# PHP 404 not found page with no redirect + include page

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

i have a problem when creating custom 404 not found.

so, i had try with .htaccess :

```
ErrorDocument 404 http://blablabla.com/404.php
```

it's working!

but the problem was it's using REDIRECT. whenever i type blablabla.com/sdkfsdkjfksdhfksd

it's redirect to blablabla.com/404.php

it's changing the **current URL**, that's not cool. it's ugly.

what i suppose to do :

whenever i type blablabla.com/sdkfsdkjfksdhfksd

**NO REDIRECT, STAY ON SAME URL**. just `require_once` custom `404.php` page.

so, i try this code :

```
<?php
    header($_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"]." 404 Not Found");
    require_once "404.php";
?>
```

i put it on top before anycode. 
and this method not working. it's showing on every single page. i try type on URL blablabla.com/sdfjnsfjnksdf

the page show up with

> Object not found!
>
> The requested URL was not found on this server. If you entered the URL
>   manually please check your spelling and try again.
>
> If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

how to get this things done?

what's wrong with my code?

thanks in advance...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to stay on the same Url, use absolute path instead of the full url for error handler .

change

```
ErrorDocument 404 http://blablabla.com/404.php
```

to

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
```

This will rewrite error pages to /404.php

Comment: is this method change the URL?  for example www.test.com/sdfksdfksdfkfsk to www.test.com/404.php

Comment: No, it doesnt change the url.

Comment: you re right! wow! that's awesome! thank you so much starkeen!

Answer (score 2):

Working solution:

.htacces:

```
 ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I do

```
 ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
```

The URL will be same but the `404.php` page will be printed. So, that's probably what you want.

Comment: damn! so, the problem was -> " http:// " that's why its changing the URL. you re so nice! thanks Coder Dude Twodee!